# Installing XFCE4 on raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-stretch, xorg, desktop

I want to try out XFCE4 on the raspberry pi. This is mainly because of two reasons:

► I just like XFCE
► I want a bit more flexibility when it comes to GUI scaling - I have a 240x320 LCD and need to scale the GUI to suit, and Pixel (LXDE I understand) doesn't seem to have an option to do that (any help on that would be nice too).

**What I have done:**

Installed XFCE
`sudo apt-get install xfce4 x-window-system`

Started it with
`startxfce4`

**The problem:**

The screen goes blank for a second when I try to `startxfce4`, and then it exits with `xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`.

The full log file can be found [here](https://paste.debian.net/1066105).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xorg often needs root permissions to run properly, so it can be problematic to start it as a non-root user from the console. If you want to run it manually without `sudo`, you should install `xserver-xorg-legacy` package containing a [wrapper](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xserver-xorg-legacy/Xwrapper.config.5.en.html) which will get root permissions for you via `suid` bit.

Alternatively, set up XFCE as your default desktop environment (the way LXDE was configured), then you will not need to start it manually.

Comment: Yes, running it as root worked! I should have thought of that....

Comment: @Jachdich Note that running Xorg as root without the wrapper has other annoying consequences, such as root-owned config files in your home folder and some programs intentionally refusing to work when they detect you're running them as root.

Comment: OK, I'll look into setting up that wrapper then.

Comment: I installed the wrapper, everything works great!

Comment: To avoid running Xorg as root you can specify the tty you are logged into by running `startx -- vt#`       where # is the number of the tty you are logged into.